# How do I create a foreign key on two columns that are under the primary key constraint?

Tags: oracle, foreign-keys, oracle12c

```
CREATE TABLE "RESEARCH_DEP"."RESEARCH_TV_COMPANY" 
   (    "CID" NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SOURCE_ID" NUMBER(2,0), 
     CONSTRAINT "PK_RESEARCH_TV_COMPANY_1" PRIMARY KEY ("CID", "SOURCE_ID")
  USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "RESEARCH_DEP"."IDX_TV_COMPANY_CID_SOURCE_ID" ON "RESEARCH_DEP"."RESEARCH_TV_COMPANY" ("CID", "SOURCE_ID")




CREATE TABLE "RESEARCH_DEP"."RESEARCH_METRICS_PHARMA_AUD" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "SOURCE_ID" NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "MEDIA_COMPANY_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE
   )
```

NEED

```
ALTER TABLE RESEARCH_DEP.RESEARCH_METRICS_PHARMA_AUD
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_METRICS_PHARMA_AUD_TV_COMPANY_ID
FOREIGN KEY (MEDIA_COMPANY_ID,SOURCE_ID) REFERENCES RESEARCH_DEP.RESEARCH_TV_COMPANY(CID,SOURCE_ID);
```

> ORA-02298: parent keys not found

DO I NEED TO CREATE A COMPOSITION COLUMN: CID,SOURCE_ID?
OR
create sequence of values two column oracle CID,SOURCE_ID ?

Comment: Please show all the DDL for all the related tables

Comment: @OldProgrammer, duplicate keys found...perhaps because of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is more or less OK:

```
SQL> create table research_tv_company
  2    (cid       number,
  3     source_id number,
  4     --
  5     constraint pk_rtc primary key (cid, source_id)
  6    );

Table created.

SQL> create table research_metrics_pharma_aud
  2    (id               number,
  3     source_id        number,
  4     media_company_id number
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> alter table research_metrics_pharma_aud
  2    add constraint fk_rmpa_rtc
  3    foreign key (media_company_id, source_id)
  4    references research_tv_company (cid, source_id);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Note that I

- removed double quotes
- removed `NOT NULL` for primary key columns (they can't be `NULL` anyway)
- don't have any indexes created so Oracle will - along with table creation - create a primary key constraint AND unique index to support it
- as I'm on 11gXE and it doesn't support identity columns, I removed that
  from the second table; I'd have to enforce it via a trigger. You don't have to do anything about it, just saying (so that you wouldn't wonder *where did it go?*)

Error you got:

> ORA-02298: parent keys not found

means that there are combinations of (`media_company_id, source_id`) in the second table that do **not exist** as pairs of (`cid, source_id`) in the first table. To illustrate it:

Drop the foreign key constraint first (otherwise, I wouldn't be able to do that):

```
SQL> alter table research_metrics_pharma_aud drop constraint fk_rmpa_rtc;

Table altered.
```

Insert a row into the first (master) table:

```
SQL> insert into research_tv_company (cid, source_id) values (1, 1);

1 row created.
```

Insert two rows into the second (detail) table; the first combination is valid, the second is not as (2, 2) don't exist in `research_tv_company`:

```
SQL> insert into research_metrics_pharma_aud (id, source_id, media_company_id) values (1, 1, 1);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into research_metrics_pharma_aud (id, source_id, media_company_id) values (2, 2, 2);

1 row created.

SQL>
```

If we try to create a foreign key constraint:

```
SQL> alter table research_metrics_pharma_aud
  2    add constraint fk_rmpa_rtc
  3    foreign key (media_company_id, source_id)
  4    references research_tv_company (cid, source_id);
  add constraint fk_rmpa_rtc
                 *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-02298: cannot validate (SCOTT.FK_RMPA_RTC) - parent keys not found


SQL>
```

See? The same error you got.

What can you do?

- insert missing primary key values into the master table, or
- delete detail rows that violate the constraint, or
- create the constraint, but instruct Oracle **not** to check whether existing rows are valid or not:

  ```
  SQL> alter table research_metrics_pharma_aud
    2    add constraint fk_rmpa_rtc
    3    foreign key (media_company_id, source_id)
    4    references research_tv_company (cid, source_id)
    5    enable novalidate;

  Table altered.

  SQL>
  ```

  The `enable novalidate` means that foreign key constraint will be enabled for any new or modified rows, but **existing** rows won't be checked. If that option suits you, use it. However, I believe that one of the first two option is better, with the first one - adding missing primary keys - being the best.

Comment: insert missing primary key values into the master table ...-This is the best for my task.

Comment: Exactly, Maksim, I agree.